# Insert row in Excel (late binding)

Tags: c#, excel

I'm trying to insert row into Excel. I'm using late binding. I opened excel workbook, copy sheet, insert values into cell, but i cant figure it out how to insert new row after specific row.

Answer (score 1):

i have hobby project for controling MS Office from .NET: [MS Office for .NET](http://www.codeplex.com/msofficefornet) - there is some little samples.

The best way to determine how to do something. Is open excel, start macro recording, do what I want do programatacily, stop macro recording and then look to VBA and copy the code to my project.